# detecting current IU android app

Tags: android

I want create an intentservice android application which can send a string to current application which have an edittext and I don't have the code source of this current app.my question is : is that possible to send data to other application ? if yes how can I detect the edittext of the current application?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data between applications through intents only if the other application is ready to handle your data. There is a good training [in Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/sharing/index.html).

Also you can use [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for interconnections, but the other app should also allow you to pass the data to it.

**In any way, if you cannot modify the code of current app to handle your data, you cannot send data to this app.**

Comment: I'm new in android programming , I was thinking that I can send a text to an other application without having access to the code ,like a keyboard application, is that possible ?

Comment: In this case, if you want to type something in `EditText`, you should create your own Input Method. There are many amazing instructions to do this, such as: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html or http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615. But you need the access to code any way) Do you write a keylogger?)

Comment: hi it's me  again , I follow the tuto,and I wanna send the character "A " to an other application so I write sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A); in my onStartInput method but it dosn't work can you help me please